# Trying to create a trending formula based on certain conditions

Tags: javascript

I have five articles with these initial properties:

```
const articles = [
  { id: 1, views: 92, likes: 0, shares: 2, trendingValue: ? },
  { id: 2, views: 14, likes: 2, shares: 1, trendingValue: ? },
  { id: 3, views: 39, likes: 3, shares: 1, trendingValue: ? },
  { id: 4, views: 87, likes: 0, shares: 1, trendingValue: ? },
  { id: 5, views: 8,  likes: 1, shares: 0, trendingValue: ? }
];
```

I also have a global stats object that should be automatically updated once an article gets new views, likes or shares (or once a week):

```
const stats = {
  totalArticles: 5,
  totalViews: 240,
  totalLikes: 6,
  totalShares: 5,
  trendingCriteria: 0
};
```

So far, I believe there is some sort of formula that can be done with articles' `trendingValue` and stats' `trendingCriteria`. Basically the articles that are "trending" need to have an equal or higher number than the criteria. Meaning that whenever an article gets a new view, share or like, `trendingValue` has to be updated in regards to it's percentage of views, likes and shares, by the global stats' counterparts.

An example (which doesn't exactly work) is:

1. A user views article 1.
2. This formula runs for the article to create its `trendingValue`:

   ```
   const article = articles[0]; // Article with id 1
   article.views++; // Increment the views count
   stats.totalViews++ // Increment the total views count

   let percentSum = (
     (article.views / stats.totalViews) + // = 0.3833
     (article.likes / stats.totalLikes) + // = 0
     (article.shares / stats.totalShares) // = 0.4
   ); // = 0.7833

   // The trendingValue needs to be a higher value of trendingCriteria
   // before refreshing trendingCriteria.
   article.trendingValue = (stats.trendingCriteria +
     (percentSum / stats.trendingCriteria)
   );
   ```
3. Next, `trendingCriteria` should be refreshed in regards to the updated article. The underlying logic is; if the new `trendingCriteria` is higher than the article's `trendingValue`, the article should no longer be "trending".

The third step is where I'm stuck. How do I create this value? Can this value be update for every single new view, like and share? Or do I have to update the value once a week or so?

## Update

Thanks for all responses. Unfortunately I could not make any use of them since I'm yet confused what to do with the proposed solutions.

Anyhow, I tried another solution that makes use of an epoch timestamp and the average views, likes and shares. Not sure if it works in practice, so if anyone can confirm I'd be grateful.

```js
function refreshArticleAtIndex(index, props) {
  const data = articles[index];
 
  // Increment props
  if(props.view) { data.views++; stats.views++; }
    else if(props.like) { data.likes++; stats.likes++; }
    else if(props.share) { data.shares++; stats.shares++; }
  
  // Refresh trendingRate
  data.trendingRate = (() => {
   const calcViews = data.views / stats.views;
   const calcLikes = data.likes / stats.likes;
   const calcShares = data.shares / stats.shares;
   let value = Date.now() * (
      (isFinite(calcViews) ? calcViews : 0) +
      (isFinite(calcLikes) ? calcLikes : 0) +
      (isFinite(calcShares) ? calcShares : 0)
    );
    
   return Math.round(value);
  })();
}

function logArticles() {
  const arr = articles.map(article => article);
  
  arr.sort((a, b) => a.trendingRate > b.trendingRate ? -1 : 1);
  arr.forEach(a => console.log(a.id +"  |", a.trendingRate));
  console.log("----------");
}

const stats = { views: 239, likes: 6, shares: 5 };
const articles = [
  { id: 1, views: 91, likes: 0, shares: 2, trendingRate: 0 },
  { id: 2, views: 14, likes: 2, shares: 1, trendingRate: 0 },
  { id: 3, views: 39, likes: 3, shares: 1, trendingRate: 0 },
  { id: 4, views: 87, likes: 0, shares: 1, trendingRate: 0 },
  { id: 5, views: 8,  likes: 1, shares: 0, trendingRate: 0 }
];

console.log("ID | trendingRate");

// ================================================

// Add 1 view to article 1
refreshArticleAtIndex(0, { view: true });

// Add nothing to below articles, but refresh their trendingRate
refreshArticleAtIndex(1, {});
refreshArticleAtIndex(2, {});
refreshArticleAtIndex(3, {});
refreshArticleAtIndex(4, {});

logArticles();

// Add 1 like to article 1
refreshArticleAtIndex(0, { like: true });

logArticles();
```

The first log will show the correct order based on a combination of views, likes and shares for each article. Next, article 1 gets a like, which bumps it to the most trending article.

Question is if this is a working solution?

Comment: how do you judge `trendingValue` with zero?

Comment: `trendingValue` that equals to 0 are new articles that have zero views, like and shares. However, since I'm asking for a working formula for this value, I just set it to 0 here in the example. So it doesn't mean anything in this case. EDIT: I changed them to question marks now.

Comment: percentSum should be a geomean instead of simple total or average :)

Comment: usually a trend is dependant on time. So it doesn't rely on all values but only the latest ones. "How many views, likes, shares have happenned in the last 24 hours" (or whatever your lifecycle is) and computing your rating from these stats.

Comment: @Thomas - That is true. But what if I implement a timestamp to the trending rate for each article? Please have a look at my update I recently posted.

Answer (score 0):

Trending probably should mean something like "top n% of activity" or "top n articles by activity".

Towards this end, you could simply save the trendingValue to an array like: `{ article: articleId, trendingValue: trendingValue}`

Then when you go to find the most trending articles you would:

```
let cnt = trendingValues.length * myLimit
let i = 0
let trending = trendingValues.sort((a,b) => a.trendingValue > b.trendingValue).filter(() => i++ < cnt)
```

To use your language, trendingCriteria could be set to some minimum based on the set of articles. From there it could be fine tuned to ensure a certain minimum activity (as the average article age starts to grow).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I don't understand what to do with this. Would you mind have a check on my update I posted?